# How to make the background of a picture invisible?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to add a picture on a button. But the background colour is different as the button-color.
How do I change the background make transparent/invisible?

The background-colour of the picture of this button has to change...

[image]

... to this one

[image]

Thanks, Wes

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? Windows Phone? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WinForms:

Select the PictureBox -> properties -> BackColor -> web -> Transparent

Comment: In the ImageList property I found TransparentColour. In this case I could choose the colour Magenta, because the four images had the same background colour.

Answer (score 0):

What's the image type?
If it's a Bitmap object, you probably have a 24 bit bgr image.  To get it to be transparent, you would need to make it a 32 bit bgra image and change every pixel which has the background color to have 0 in the a channel.
If it's an 8-bit color-mapped image, you would change the palette entry for the background color to a color with 0 in the a channel.

Comment: I use an ImageList. I remember it was quite simple with a Delphi-application.

Comment: You don't have to editing the image self. It was by changing a property. No I think you have to do nothing.